# I cannot change the size dimensions of StackView

Tags: uistackview

Simple.  I have a StackView in Storyboard and width and height are greyed out.  I cannot change the size.  Nor can I change the frames of any of its `arrangedSubviews`.  Their size properties of greyed out as well.  Why is this?